# Do i need to change Spring Boot configuration when new member added in Mongo DB Replica Set

Tags: spring-boot, mongodb-replica-set

In my Spring Boot project i have configured Mongo DB replica set successfully.
Now if i add new member to the already defined replica set , do i need to change spring boot mongo uri properties.
Is there any other mechanism through which if I add replica set member but not require to change my spring boot configuration.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using DNS seed list (`mongodb+srv...`) with a single host, your Mongo driver would look up all the hosts. So `mongodb+srv://<user>:<pass>@mydomain.mongodb.net"` can be resolved to `mydomain-shard-00, mydomain-shard-01..`. Otherwise you have to specify all the members in `spring.data.mongodb.uri`

Answer (score 0):

When mongodb driver connects to replica set it figures out all the nodes of replica. Even when you add new node it finds it out. But imagine you configured only one node in your spring configuration, then started your application. Once everything is working node configured in your configuration goes down. But still your application continues working as it has figured out other nodes. But if you restart your application it will not be able to connect as you have configured only one node and that is not available. So as good practice always specify all or majority of the nodes in configuration.